# Вывод данных из многомерного массива JSON

Tags: javascript, массивы, ajax, json, циклы

Подскажите, как вывести данные из такого массива в JS? Его я получаю как JSON после AJAX запроса.

Вот что отображается в консоли, когда приходят данные:

```
{main: Array(1), tags: Array(3), time: Array(0), invites: Array(5)}

invites: Array(5)
 0: {id: "1", usesMail: "user@mail.ru", userFirst: "Name", userLast: "Last", userNik: "user", …}
 1: {id: "2", usesMail: "user@mail.ru", userFirst: "Name 1", userLast: "Last", userNik: "user", …}
 2: {id: "5", usesMail: "user@mail.ru", userFirst: "Name 2", userLast: "Last", userNik: "user", …}
 3: {id: "6", usesMail: "user@mail.ru", userFirst: "Name 3", userLast: "Last", userNik: "user", …}
 4: {id: "7", usesMail: "user@mail.ru", userFirst: "Name 4", userLast: "Last", userNik: "user", …}

main: Array(1)
 0: {id: "16", userCreator: "user@mail.ru", taskHash: "7e7b36", taskTitle: "testing new", taskCom: "test comment", …}

tags: Array(3)
 0: {id: "11", taskHash: "7e7b36", taskId: "empty", tagName: "#personal"}
 1: {id: "12", taskHash: "7e7b36", taskId: "empty", tagName: "#wtf"}
 2: {id: "13", taskHash: "7e7b36", taskId: "empty", tagName: "#love"}

time: Array(0)
```

Не могу понять как сформировать цикл, чтобы получить каждое значение. Пробую через `for`, но чувствую, что не то.

```
for (var x in obj) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем у меня получилось вывести нужные результаты с таким кодом. Буду рад, если сможете помочь оптимизировать его, я не очень силен в js.

Я вывел каждый массив отдельно, а затем разобрал его на значения.

```
                    var mainInfo = data.main;
                    for (var i = 0; i < mainInfo.length; i++) {
                        var mainList = mainInfo[i];
                        for (property in mainList) {
                            //var value = mainList[property];
                            console.log(mainList['taskHash']); 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    var timeInfo = data.time;
                    for (var i = 0; i < timeInfo.length; i++) {
                        var timeList = timeInfo[i];
                        for (property in timeList) {
                            //var value = mainList[property];
                            console.log(timeList['setTime']); 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    var tagInfo = data.tags;
                    for (var i = 0; i < tagInfo.length; i++) {
                        var tagList = tagInfo[i];
                        for (property in tagList) {
                            //var value = mainList[property];
                            console.log(tagList['tagName']); 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    var invInfo = data.invites;
                    for (var i = 0; i < invInfo.length; i++) {
                        var invList = invInfo[i];
                        for (property in invList) {
                            //var value = mainList[property];
                            console.log(invList['userFirst']+" "+invList['userLast']); 
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.main.forEach(mainList=>console.log(mainList.taskHash))
...
```